# Factoring irreducible fractions

Tags: factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Is there a technique or a formula that factors irreducible fractions into products of polynomials, for example:
$$\frac1{x^8+1}=\frac{1}{(x^4+ \sqrt2x^2+1)(x^4- \sqrt2x^2+1)}$$
Also, is there a way to factor, in the same way as above, the following fraction:
$$\frac1{x^4-x^2+1}$$
I am not interested in the completition of the square. Thank you.

Comment: `I am not interested in the completition of the square.` Why? That's the easiest most direct way in both cases.

Comment: What do you mean by `irreducible`? In your first example, the appearance of $\sqrt{2}$ suggests that you're factoring over reals. But then neither of the two polynomials is irreducible (meaning both can be factored further over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @zipirovich my mistake

Comment: @Denis Wonder why ask about $\frac{1}{x^8+1}$ instead of $x^8+1$ directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the "*without completion of the square*" part of the question, it is possible to actually determine the roots of the given polynomials in both cases. Then grouping each root with its complex conjugate gives a quadratic in $x$ which is a factor of the original polynomial.

In the case of $x^8+1$ for example, a pair of roots is $x = \cos(\frac{\pi}{8}) \pm i \sin(\frac{\pi}{8})\,$. The quadratic which has those roots is $x^2 - 2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{8})\,x +1\,$. Using the half-angle formula, $\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\,$. Therefore a factor of $x^8+1$ is:

$$x^2 - \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \,x + 1$$

Since $x^8 +1$ is an even polynomial, another factor follows by substituting $x \mapsto -x\,$:

$$x^2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \,x + 1$$

Their product, which itself must be a factor of $x^8+1$ is:

$$\left(x^2 - \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \,x + 1\right)\left(x^2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \,x + 1\right) \;=\; x^4 - \sqrt{2} \,x^2 + 1$$

Dividing $x^8+1$ by the above gives the other factor $\;x^4 + \sqrt{2} \,x^2 + 1\,$.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor second fraction as $$\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 4 }-x^{ 2 }+1 } =\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 4 }+2x^{ 2 }+1-3{ x }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ { \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }^{ 2 }-{ \left( \sqrt { 3 } x \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1-\sqrt { 3 } x \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1+\sqrt { 3 } x \right)  }  $$

Answer (score 0):

One has a direct way, writing
$$
x^8+1=(x^8+2x^4+1)-2x^4=(x^4+1)^2-2x^4=(x^4+ \sqrt2x^2+1)(x^4- \sqrt2x^2+1)
$$ similarly
$$
x^4-x^2+1=(x^4+1)-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-3x^2=(x^2+ \sqrt3x+1)(x^2- \sqrt3x+1).
$$